# Matlab find() function in R

Tags: r, matlab, find, cumsum

I am trying to convert some Matlab code into R. The code looks something like this:

```
u= [.4 .5 .1;
    .2 .4 .4;
    .4 .1 .5]
z= find(cumsum(u)>= rand,1)

OUTPUT: e.g. z = 3
```

The mathematical background is described like this (from a math tut. script):

> We make a vector containing the cumulative sum of the columns (which
> we know sum to one),  generate a random number (0-1),and then use the
> find function to take  the first number in the cumulative sum vector
> that is >= the random number.  For example if our D vector is [.5 .5]
> 50% of the time the element of the  vector corresponding to the state
> one will be >= to the random number. https://psyarxiv.com/b4jm6/

I have tried to use `find()` from the `pracma` package(docu. link below), but I don't know how to get it working. I get either `"dims[product...] do not match the length of object"` or mostly just `"is.character(what) is not TRUE"`...

Matlab function:

```
k = find(x,n)
```

returns the first n indices corresponding to the nonzero elements in X.
https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

`find()` from the R package `pracma`, which only seems to conver `find(x)`:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pracma/versions/1.1.0/topics/find

Comment: Are you looking for `which(cumsum(u)>= runif(1))[1]`?

Comment: Did not work. It should correspond to this matlab function for the case k = find(x,n): https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html

Comment: k = find(x,n) returns the first n indices corresponding to the nonzero elements in X.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: No, it actually seems to work. Thank you!!!

Comment: Please do not add the answer to the question. Rather answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by @Rui Barradas: `which(cumsum(u)>= runif(1))[1]`